# BatchNorm makes accuracy at prediction time around 10% of what's reported during training in tensorflow 2.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I know this has been previously discussed, but I did not find a concrete answer, and some answers did not work after trying them, the case is simple, I have a model, if I use batch norm, the training accuracy reported by `model.fit(training_data)` is above 0.9 (it consistently increases, and the loss decreases), but then after training if I run `model.evaluate(training_data)` (notice is the same data) it returns 0.09, also predictions are really bad (the accuracy is low too if manually calculated using the results from `model.predict(training_data)`. I know the difference between training and testing time in batch norm, and I know differences should be expected, but a drop from 0.9 to 0.09 seems just wrong(and the model is completely unusable). I tried some solutions from other threads:

- use batch_size in `.evaluate` to be the same as `.fit`: did not make a difference
- set `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)`: got a message saying it is now deprecated and made no difference.
- set all batch norm layers to have `layer.trainable=False` before `.predict` and `.evaluate`: it did not a difference.

If I remove batch norm layers, the report from `model.fit(training_data)` coincides with `model.evaluate(training_data)` but the training is not doing any progress (results are consistent but bad) so I need to add it.

Is this a major bug in TF 2.6?

Update: also tested TF 2.5, result is the same.

Sample code(omitting irrelevant code, like data reading and pre-processing):

```
    ### model definition
 
class CLS_BERT_Embedding(tf.keras.Model):
    """Will only use the CLS token"""
    def __init__(self, bert_trainable=False,  number_filters=50,FNN_units=512,
               number_clases=2,dropout_rate=0.1,name="dcnn"):
        super(CLS_BERT_Embedding,self).__init__(name)
        self.checkpoint_id ="CLS_BERT_Embedding_bn_3fc_{}filters_{}fc_units_berttrainable{}".format(number_filters,
                                                                                FNN_units,bert_trainable)
 
        # trainable= False so we don't fine-tune bert, just use as embedding layer
        self.bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1", 
                                          trainable=bert_trainable,
                                         input_shape=(3,376))
 
 
        self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(units = FNN_units,activation="relu")
        self.bn1 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(units = FNN_units, activation="relu")
        self.bn2 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.dense_3 = layers.Dense(units = FNN_units, activation="relu")
        self.bn3 = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.dropout = layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)
 
        if number_clases == 2:
            self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=1,activation="sigmoid")
        else:
            self.last_dense = layers.Dense(units=number_clases,activation="softmax")
 
    def get_bert_embeddings(self,all_tokens):
        CLS_embedding ,embeddings = self.bert_layer([all_tokens[:,0,:],
                                        all_tokens[:,1,:],
                                        all_tokens[:,2,:]])
 
        return CLS_embedding,embeddings
 
    def call(self,inputs,training):
        CLS_embedding, x_seq = self.get_bert_embeddings(inputs)
        
        
        x = self.dense_1(CLS_embedding)
        x = self.bn1(x,training)
        x = self.dense_2(x)
        x = self.bn2(x,training)
        x = self.dense_3(x)
        x = self.bn3(x,training)
        
        output = self.last_dense(x)
 
 
        return output
 
#### config and hyper-params
NUMBER_FILTERS = 1024
FNN_UNITS = 2048
BERT_TRAINABLE = False
 
NUMBER_CLASSES = len(tokenizer.vocab)
 
DROPOUT_RATE = 0.2
 
NUMBER_EPOCHS = 3
LR = 0.001
 
DEVICE = '/GPU:0'
 
#### optimization definition
with tf.device(DEVICE):
    model = CLS_BERT_Embedding(
                bert_trainable = BERT_TRAINABLE,
                number_filters=NUMBER_FILTERS,
                FNN_units=FNN_UNITS,
                number_clases=NUMBER_CLASSES,
                dropout_rate = DROPOUT_RATE)
 
if NUMBER_CLASSES == 2:
    loss = "binary_crossentropy"
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
else:
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
    metrics = ["sparse_categorical_accuracy"]
 
    
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = LR)
loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer,metrics=metrics)
 
 
### training
with tf.device(DEVICE):
    model.fit(train_dataset,
             batch_size = BATCH_SIZE ,
             epochs=NUMBER_EPOCHS,
             shuffle=True,
             callbacks=[MyCustomCallback(), 
                        
                        tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="loss",patience=5),
                        tensorboard,lr_tensorboard])
 
 
### testing
train_results = model.evaluate(train_dataset,batch_size = BATCH_SIZE)
print(train_results)
```

Comment: That's strange. Can you show us the code?

Comment: @AdarshWase I added the relevant parts of the code here: https://pastebin.com/XyY6TXY5

Comment: Please don't host code somewhere else. Post it here

Comment: What happens if you move the evalution under the tf.device(DEVICE) context( i.e. tab in once on the evaluation line)?  Is it possible it is using untrained weights under the default device context if DEVICE is not the same as the default?

Comment: @MikeHolcomb, I tested it, the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Try running inference without adjusting the trainable flag at all and then verifying that self.bn1.trainable=True. Then run forward prop by calling the model as a callable on each batch of your training data but with training=True, and evaluating each time. So that would be something like

```
for idx d in enumerate(train_dataset_:
  _ = model(d[0], training=True)
  model.evaluate(d)
  if idx > 100:
    break
```

If your loss starts dropping, then this is an example of your batch norm moving statistics not updating fast enough, which is possible given the BNs are not trained but your bert mode/layer is. If not, ignore the rest of this because you may have a different issue.

If that's the case, you have two options. One is to keep calling the model  to allow the BN moving statistics to stabilize.

The other is to statistically analyze the output of your bert layer (get the mean and var) and directly update the BN's moving statistic weights. Probably the first BN is sufficient given your latter Dense layers are
Xavier Glorot initialized, but given you are using Relu, you might also try Kaiming He initialization on them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Yaoshiang, it is likely that the internal statistics (moving average, moving var) do not coincide with the mean and variance per batch, hence a different normalization in the BN layer at training and at testing. Thinking about it, if we use the same batch size for training and testing, then we can keep training=True in the test without it being a real problem (when using predict or evaluate). Otherwise, we can force in the training to use the moving average and moving variance for the normalization rather than the mean and variance by batch and still estimate beta and gamma. (This implies a minor modification of the BatchNormalization class.)

Comment: Thank you, any suggested material for your comment: Otherwise, we can force in the training to use the moving average and moving variance for the normalization rather than the mean and variance by batch and still estimate beta and gamma. (This implies a minor modification of the BatchNormalization class.)